# accessing value in a hash of hashes

Tags: perl, hash

I'm having trouble accessing a hash value and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I do some Perl but not much with hashes.

I'm trying to access hash value in a hash of hashes.

Here is where I build the Hash

```
sub buildList
{
    my ($name,$gender,$father,$mother,$age);
    my %bear_ref=();

    open IN, "<input.txt" or die "can't open file";

    while(<IN>) {
        ($name, $gender, $father, $mother, $age ) = split(/:/);
        $bear_ref{ $name } { 'gender' } = $gender;
        $bear_ref{ $name } { 'mother' } = $father;
        $bear_ref{ $name } { 'father' } = $mother;
        $bear_ref{ $name } { 'age' } = $age;
    }
    close IN;
    return \%bear_ref;
}
```

I can access the list when I am itereting through the keys in the hash but not directly. So I'm assuming it has something to do with the way i'm getting the value from the "keys() loop"

```
for my $name (keys %$ref) {
   $father= $ref->{ $name }->{ 'father'}; # works
   $mother= $ref->{ $name }->{ 'mother'}; # works
   getTree($name, $ref);
}

sub getTree
{
    my $bear = shift;
    my $ref = shift;
    my ($father, $mother);
     $father= $ref->{ $name }->{ 'father'}; # doesn't work...have also tried with %$ref->
     $mother= $ref->{ $name }->{ 'mother'}; # doesn't work...have also tried with %$ref->
    print "$father : $mother\n";

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Always [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) until you know exactly why it is recommended.

Answer (score 3):

`$name` should be `$bear` in the `getTree` sub.

```
sub getTree
{
    my $bear = shift;
    my $ref = shift;
    my ($father, $mother);
    ## note that I am using $bear instead of $name since $name is not defined
    $father= $ref->{ $bear }->{ 'father'};
    $mother= $ref->{ $bear }->{ 'mother'};
    print "$father : $mother\n";
}
```

**Note:** `use strict` and `use warnings` would be helpful.

Comment: wow, ok now I feel dumb. thanks. Yeah I use strict and warnings but I forgot to put the output.  Either way I think I have it now. Thanks again.